# Serial Port Closed in Form3?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with writing to my serial port in my Form3.
I am able to write/read from the serial port in form 1. And i can connect to serial port in form 2.
However when I try to write to the serial Port in from3. I get an error saying the serial port is closed, this if weird because I did not close the serial port. I have been looking through the internet to find a solution however I have not found one that helps my situation. I can not use a static serial port because my program had a drop down menu with all the available ports and the user is given the choice of which serial port to use.

Form 1 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using ZedGraph;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ECE
{
    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
        double temp;
        int flag = 1;
        double x = 0;
        int init = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        double temp1;
  
       
        private T_settings t_settings;


        private Bluetooth_Settings _setting = new Bluetooth_Settings();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            int text_length = 0;
            
            text_length = richTextBox1.TextLength;
            char send_ch = richTextBox1.Text[text_length - 1]; // extracting the last character
            char[] ch = new char[1];
            ch[0] = send_ch;
            if (send_ch == '\n')
            {
                _setting._serial.Write("\r"); // sending carraige return 
            }
            else
            {
                _setting._serial.Write(ch, 0, 1); // sending char to microcontroller
            }
        }

        private void blueToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void toolStripProgressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void COMPortToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _setting.Show();                                 
            _setting._serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);                          
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            
            if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
                int count = sp.Read(buffer, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
                Extract_each_Character(buffer, count);
             
            }
            
        }

        private void Extract_each_Character(byte[] buffer, int count)
        {
            byte data;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                data = buffer[i];
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(update_richtextbox1), new object[] { data });

            }

        }

        private void update_richtextbox1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
           

            byte data = (byte)sender;
            char s = Convert.ToChar(data);

                richTextBox1.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(richTextBox1_TextChanged); // removing text changed event 
                richTextBox1.AppendText(s.ToString());
                SerialPort1_DataReceived(s.ToString());
            richTextBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(richTextBox1_TextChanged); // adding text changed event
            
        }

        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(string s)
        {
            
            if (s.Length != 0)
            {

                if (s.Contains("Celcuis")) // Celcuius 
                {
                    flag = 1;
                                  
                }
                
                else if (s.Contains("Fahrenheit")) // Farenhieght
                {
                    flag = 2;                   
                }

                else if (s.All(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    AddTextToLabel(s);
                }
                    
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
        }



        private void CreateChart(ZedGraphControl zedGraphControl1)
        {

            // Declare a new GraphPane Object 
            GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
            if (init == 0)
            {

                // Set the titles and axis labels
                myPane.Title.Text = "Moffat Omuya Temp. Graph";
                myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time, Seconds";
                myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Temprature in F";

                // Make up some data pointw based on the Sine function 
                // Note: All data being plotted by zedgraph have to be “Double” format.
                // Data should be saved as a PointPairList before plotting.
                // So “List.Add()” method should be called after you define or
                // change the data that are plotted.
                // Generate a red curve with diamond symbols, and "Alpha" in the legend


                LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Fahrenheight", list, Color.Red);
                // Fill the symbols with white
                myCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);
                // Generate a blue curve with circle symbols, and "Beta" in the legend
                //Some enhancing setting:
                // Show the x axis grid
                init = 1;
            }

            else if (init == 1)
            {

                myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
                // Make the Y axis scale red
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Red;
                myPane.YAxis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Red;
                // Don't display the Y zero line
                myPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsZeroLine = false;
                // Align the Y axis labels so they are flush to the axis
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.Align = AlignP.Inside;
                // Manually set the axis range
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 100;
                // Fill the axis background with a gradient
                myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightGray, 45.0f);
                // Calculate the Axis Scale Ranges
                //Note: ZedGraphControl.AxisChange() command keep checking and
                // adjusting the display axis setting according to the List changes.
                zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            }



        }

        

        public void AddTextToLabel(string str)
        {
            
         
            if (flag == 1) // Celcuis 
            {
                //list Adding Function 1;
                if (digit == 0)
                {
                    temp = Double.Parse(str);
                    digit++;
                }

                else if (digit == 1)
                {
                    temp1 = Double.Parse(str);
                    temp = temp * 10 + temp1;
                    digit++;
                }
                
                else if (digit == 2)
                    {
                    double y = temp;
                    //digit = 0;
                    temp = 0;
                    temp1 = 0;

                    digit =0;
                    x++;
                    list.Add(x, y);
                    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                    CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
                }
                
                else if (digit == 3)
                {
                    temp1 = Double.Parse(str);
                    digit++;
                }

                else if (digit == 4)
                {
                    temp = Double.Parse(str);
                    temp = temp * 10 + temp1;
                    digit++;
                }
                else if (digit == 5)
                {
                    double y = temp;
                    digit = 0;
                    temp = 0;
                    temp1 = 0;

                    
                    x++;
                    list.Add(x, y);
                    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                    CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
                }

             

            }
            if (flag == 2) // Farenheight
            {
                //List Adding Function 2;
                if (digit == 0)
                {
                    temp = Double.Parse(str);
                    digit++;
                }

                else if (digit == 1)
                {
                    temp1 = Double.Parse(str);
                    temp = temp * 10 + temp1;
                    digit++;
                }

                else if (digit == 2)
                {
                    double y = temp;
                    //digit = 0;
                    temp = 0;
                    temp1 = 0;

                    digit++;
                    x++;
                    list.Add(x, y);
                    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                    CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
                }
                else if (digit == 3)
                {
                    temp1 = Double.Parse(str);
                    digit++;
                }

                else if (digit == 4)
                {
                    temp = Double.Parse(str);
                    temp = temp * 10 + temp1;
                    digit++;
                }
                else if (digit == 5)
                {
                    double y = temp;
                    digit = 0;
                    temp = 0;
                    temp1 = 0;


                    x++;
                    list.Add(x, y);
                    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                    CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
                }


            }
        }

        private void zedGraphControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void Toggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 2 = F , 1 = C

            char[] ch = new char[1];
            
            
                ch[0] = 'D';
                
                _setting._serial.Write(ch, 0, 1); // sending char to microcontroller
              
          
        }


        private void bluetoothSettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t_settings = new T_settings();
            t_settings.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

In Form one I have two funcitons that are able to write to the sereial port named Toggle_Click and arichTextBox1_TextChanged.

Form2 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports; // added this 

namespace ECE
{
    public partial class Bluetooth_Settings : Form
    {
        public  SerialPort _serial = new SerialPort(); // added this 
        public Bluetooth_Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _serial.BaudRate = int.Parse(baud_rate.Text); // added this 
            foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames()) // added this 
            {
                com_port.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }


       
        private void Bluetooth_Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void connet_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _serial.PortName = com_port.SelectedItem.ToString();
                _serial.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(baud_rate.SelectedItem);
                _serial.Open();
                this.Close();
                Form1 _main = new Form1();
                foreach (Form1 tmpform in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (tmpform.Name == "Form1")
                    {
                        _main = tmpform;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                _main.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = " Connected: " + _serial.PortName.ToString();
                _main.toolStripStatusLabel1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                _main.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 100;
            }
            catch
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Please select COM Port/ Baud Rate");
            }            
        }

        private void Bluetooth_Settings_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In Form two is where I make the serial port connection.

Form 3 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports; // added this 

namespace ECE
{
    
    public partial class T_settings : Form
    {
       


        private Bluetooth_Settings _enter = new Bluetooth_Settings();

        
        public T_settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        string Sampling_text;
        //Dim COMPort = Form1.COMPort



        private void Average_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void T_settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        
        private void Text_Sampling_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Sampling_text = Text_Sampling.Text;
            
        }

        private void Send_Sampling_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            int text_length = 0;

            text_length = Sampling_text.Length;
            char send_ch = Text_Sampling.Text[text_length - 1]; // extracting the last character
            char[] ch = new char[1];
            ch[0] = send_ch;
            if (send_ch == '\n')
            {
                _enter._serial.Write("\r"); // sending carraige return 
            }
            else
            {
                _enter._serial.Write(ch, 0, 1); // sending char to microcontroller
            }

            char[] enter = new char[1];


            

        }
    }
}
```

Form 3 is the form I am having trouble with. In the send sampling click function I get an error saying that the serial port is closed when I try to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues firstly when you create an instance Bluetooth_Settings none of the settings are configured (textbox values) unless you have hard coded default values already in the form which suppose to work.

Secondly the main issue is port was not opened when you write from form3

`private Bluetooth_Settings _enter = new Bluetooth_Settings();`

basically it is working in form2 because you have button events which opens the ports and set other settings, probably you should be passing values from caller and provide methods for opening ports etc from form3

```
_serial.PortName = com_port.SelectedItem.ToString();
_serial.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(baud_rate.SelectedItem);
_serial.Open();
```